# If i change my twitter username does API keys change?

Tags: api, twitter

So I'm making a twitter bot (I'm new to using api keys) , and i'm done with coding , and i thought of changing the twitter bot username , so i was wondering does it Change the API keys ?

consumer_key:
consumer_secret:
access_token:
access_token_secret:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, It doesn't.

Also note that your [user ID](http://gettwitterid.com/) does not change even if you change your screen name(@name).